# Web interface to Git repo server allowing user account self-administration

Tags: git, redmine, gitolite, gitorious, gitlab

This question is an extension of https://stackoverflow.com/q/438163/1168342 
I'd like to know specifically if there's a web interface to Git repository server allowing users to:

1. Register for an account if they haven't one already. (assume server's only visible via VPN)
2. Manage (create/share) private repos with other users on same server.

I looked at Redmine and GitLab, and both seem to require superusers to create accounts. GitLab runs on Gitolite, [which seems to support the back-end of pre-configured accounts](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/users.html). But I'm looking for something with the front-end software that manages the users/sharing.

p.s. This is also a more focused question related to [Best source code control for a university environment (low overhead to manage repositories)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9693202/1168342)

---

The solution we want should work for the entire university, allowing any registered user (p.ex. LDAP) to create and share repos without the intervention of an admin. Think >10K users, several repos per student/course (each semester), with teams created dynamically without a lab assistant or professor, as well as research/club/group usage, etc.

Comment: GitLab requires you to set up a gitolite and gitlab user only for initial setup. After that, admins can add new users through the Web interface and their can manage their own SSH keys.

Comment: I believe the "admins can add" part is exactly what Fuhrmanator does not want to have. Instead the users should be able to register independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've got an LDAP or ActiveDirectory (with LDAP open), you can allow users to log into Gitlab with their LDAP email address and password.

<strike>But an admin or project master will still need to add users to projects.</strike>

Then, to add users to projects automatically, use a System Hook. Unfortunately, the documentation for system hooks is light, and what documentation there is is not online; it's part of the Gitlab application you installed. But after you do install it, you can get to it via (http://yourgitlabhost/help/system_hooks).

You'll need to write a small web app to receive these hooks, then call the Gitlab API (http://yourgitlabhost/help/api) to add the newly logged in user to the appropriate projects.

Comment: This is a valid answer. Not sure why someone would down-vote without even commenting why. +1

Comment: @iliacholy I downvoted it before it was edited - because it said admins must add users to projects (contradicts my request in the question, not useful). As for the current version, it says "you have to write it yourself," which I still think makes the answer not useful.

Comment: Gitlab, even without LDAP and web hooks, meets the asker's requirements: it allows users to register, create projects, and share projects without an administrator. The creator of a project may add other users to that project. Only administrators, however, may add users to any project. But as I re-read the original question and comments, I see that this is not a requirement. Gitlab will work well in this scenario.

Comment: I removed my downvote an accepted. Our admins finally coded the system hook, and this is the best answer (even if it's not exactly the ideal wrt the question).

Answer (score 1):

[Gitorious](https://gitorious.org/) allows independent user registration and just recently released their first version with [private repositories](http://blog.gitorious.org/2012/02/29/private-repositories-2/).

Comment: Thanks! Adding gitorious tag to the question.

Comment: Pricing for Gitorious is steep for a university environment. "€5000 per year for up to 50 users"

Comment: Gitorious is free software. If hosted by yourself the cost is only what you need to operate and maintain your systems. If however you want someone else to host, maintain or install your Gitorious environment for you, you will have to pay him. I guess there should be special pricing available for schools and universities on request.

Comment: Thanks! I admit the propaganda on their site makes it hard to find how to install it on your own, but [here's how](http://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Installation).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to ask about possibilities for you in [Private Assembla](http://portfolio.assembla.com/private_install.html), or [build own "Assembla"](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/assembladev/),

you can think about SCM-Manager

- [scm-userrepo-plugin](http://plugins.scm-manager.org/scm-plugin-backend/page/detail/sonia.scm.plugins/scm-userrepo-plugin.html) for creating repos by users
- [scm-auth-ldap-plugin](http://plugins.scm-manager.org/scm-plugin-backend/page/detail/sonia.scm.plugins/scm-auth-ldap-plugin.html) or [scm-activedirectory-auth-plugin](http://plugins.scm-manager.org/scm-plugin-backend/page/detail/sonia.scm.plugins/scm-activedirectory-auth-plugin.html) for managing users

**Final note (offtopic)**: please, do not spoil the students by dipping them into Git

Comment: Private Assembla seems very expensive for even 100 users ($1k/month). I'll pass the SCM-Manager plugins info +1 on to our admin.